# How to find how many paragraphs in a file?

Tags: linux, grep, wc

For example

```
1006.2100 49.2000
1015.6100 47.7000
1023.1100 25.2000
1024.2200 33.3000
1025.5100 26.3000
1040.6100 29.0000


1151.57 3
169.1900 31.5000
174.9900 31.5000
193.1000 19.1000
196.4500 17.9000
197.2200 23.7000
```

the answer would be 2.  I was thinking of using grep command however i'm not how to grep a paragraph or the wc command but no option for a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` in paragraph mode (i.e. setting an empty record separator) e.g.

```
$ awk -vRS= 'END{print NR}' yourfile
2
```